# Hide / Unhide VBA Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a macro to hide a few columns that shows additional information however i can't get it to unhide the same data. I know it's simple I am just really unfamiliar with Macros. Any help would be awesome! Here is the Macro I use to hide the columns.

```
 Sub Unhide()
'
' Unhide Macro
'

'
    Columns("C:K").Select
    Range("C2").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

I also use this Macro

```
Sub Hide_E()
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
   If c.Value = "N/A" Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf c.Value = 1 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Would it be possible to add a similar code to unhide the rows I hid?

Thank you so much!!